# Sqlite on both Windows Phone 7.1 and Windows Phone 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I'm developing an app for Windows Phone 7.1(7.5) - 8 (Must work for both) , in which database connectivity is required.
This Application is already realized for Iphone and Android, so I have to use there Database file to the database structure was the same for all applications. Sqlite is used as the database .
All Sqlite Clients for Windows Phone are  out of date and not supported any more.

- http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx
- http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/
- http://www.wirebear.com/blog/2010/11/12/using-sqlite-in-your-wp7-app/
- http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/releases

Official client is only for windows phone 8 
http://www.sqlite.org/download.html 
and is not working with windows phone 7.1

Will be really helpfull if someone can give me any suggestions what i can  do with this situation.

- develop only for Windows Phone 8 and use official Sqlite Client
- use old libriaries for sqlite and try to work with them on windows phone 8
- use SQL CE as the database

(PS. : The situation is further complicated by the fact that Windows RT is not support SQL CE and only Sqlite   and it makes me crazy.)

Comment: I've been using http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/ for wp7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used sqlite in my app for windows phone 7 as described in the [dotnetslackers link](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx) and its working fine in WP 8 ( I tested in WP8 emulator).

I don't see any point for saying "All Sqlite Clients for Windows Phone are out of date and not supported any more". Did you try yourself ?

Also [this link](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/07/sqlite-metro-winmobile) says "SQLite is now supported on Windows RT, Windows 8 Metro Apps and will be supported on Windows Phone 8 for local application storage."

And here is one more [link](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/wp7/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-phone-application.htm), which I didn't test.

I suggest you to try the [dotnetslackers link](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx) and post here if you face any problem. Good luck !!

Comment: I see the last edit date. All yours examples are using http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/ which has last edit date is Last edited Nov 30, 2010. Thank you for the answer I'll try this libriary!

Answer (score 0):

Note that SQL Server Compact 4.0 does not have a release for Windows Mobile, Windows Phone or for Windows CE devices. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg592946.aspx

You can use SQL Server Compact 3.5 on WP 7.5, but I'm not sure if this version works on WP8.

Comment: SQL Server Compact 3.5 also works on WP8 and WP8.1 without any issues. No need to change any code actually.