# how to create persistent database for windows phone 8 mobile application

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

i want to create static database for windows phone 8 sdk. I dont know in windows phone what database have to use whether sqlite or sql server. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use MS Sql Server Compact DB (SQL CE), for further reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I was Looking for something similar and I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474029/sqlite-on-both-windows-phone-7-1-and-windows-phone-8

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Local Database in windows phone 8 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556607/how-to-create-a-local-database-in-windows-phone-8-app)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a popular option for adding an in-process database to your Windows Phone Apps.

You might want to read this article to learn more:

[Using the SQLite database engine with Windows Phone 8 apps](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/03/12/using-the-sqlite-database-engine-with-windows-phone-8-apps.aspx)

If you'd rather, a @rs points out above, you might also consider SQL Server Compact Edition. This article from the always awesome ErikEj should set you on the right path:

[Generate a Windows Phone 8 Local Database DataContext from an existing database](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2013/04/generate-windows-phone-8-local-database.html)

HTH.