# How to create a Local Database in windows phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, local-database

Hi i am new to windows phone 8 development,

I am developing a app which needs to store a large amount of data in local database of the app.

1) Can i know what is the most reliable option to create and store data in local database ?

2) What are the various options available for creating a local database in windows phone 8 application ?

i request to please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQLite

[Working with SQLite in Windows Phone 8: a sqlite-net version for mobile](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/working-with-sqlite-in-windows-phone-8-a-sqlite-net-version-for-mobile/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20qmatteoq_eng%20%28qmatteoq.com%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader)

[sqlite-net-wp](https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8)

There is also [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/), I don't think there is a WP8 build but it wouldn't be difficult to create one.

Answer (score 2):

I can not answer which is the most reliable, but if you want to use a built-in database you should use LINQ to SQL. See [Local database for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't think SQLCE is available for native WP8 apps.

Comment: You are right that SQL CE does not support Windows Phone 8. However, there is LINQ to SQL support in Windows Phone 8 using a local database that runs in the same process as the app and stores its data in the app folder. It is not possible to use Transact-SQL to this local database.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should try [iboxdb.net](https://iboxdb.codeplex.com/), [there have a test on pc storing a large amount of data](https://iboxdb.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Benchmark%20with%20MongoDB&referringTitle=Home),  it can run on windows phone 8 , and includes a net2.0 version that can run on android with mono