# Bing Maps on Windows Phone 7.5 - SQLite or XML

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

I creating app that using Bing Maps Api and i need to add to map 200 markers. What is the better solution for this. Can I used for this SQLite like i did in android or using XML is good enough for that number of markers?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you looking to store the markers (co-ordinates and name?) for future use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML & JSON**

If you're only dealing with 200 pins and are not likely to go over that number, then storing the pins as XML or JSON is a simple solution. GeekChamp has a nice tutorial on how to serialise/de-serialise XML...

- [All about WP7 Isolated Storage - Read and Save XML files using XmlSerializer](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage---read-and-save-xml-files)

For JSON, the code would be very similar, but instead you would use a JSON serialises such as [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) which is also available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text) (a package manager for Visual Studio). In my experience, this JSON serializer is faster than any XML version.

**Database**

With only 200 items/pins, a database maybe overkill for what you're trying to do. But if that number increases over time and you require more flexible storage then the official option is a Microsoft SQL CE database...

- [Local database for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

SQLite is only officially supported (although not built in, you have to add it) on Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 (WinRT). For Windows Phone 7, there are [ports of SQLite](http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/) which are a bit old but [others have reported they still work fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13474029/247257).